# explain basic html tags semantics

Tags: html

when you have a tag that doesn't need a closing tag I've noticed that sometimes you end with ">" and sometimes you end with "/>"

for example:

```
<img src="..."/>
<input id="x" value="y">
```

but both actually seem to work interchangeably. Why? And what is the meaning behind them?

Comment: for some reason if i showed the opening "<" than the html didn't show so i emitted it

Comment: `/` is not required in any versions of HTML, it's XHTML syntax.. though, using `/` in HTML won't harm you

Comment: go to www.w3schools.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically speaking, this goes back to one of XML's rules that all opening tags must have a closing tag.  so `<a>` must have `</a>`. if there's no content inside the tag, you could notate the close as `<a/>`.  this applies to all tags, even tho most browsers are designed to handle certain tags such as link tags because designers/devs often don't follow this rule anymore

Comment: forgot to mention that i'd suggest to at least do the "self-closing" tags (<tag/>)